# How to iterate a zero padded integer in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

How does one iterate a string with the form "[A-Z][0-9]*" Or for example: "A000001"?

After receiving the variable I split:

```
current_=$(mysql -h"$mysqlhost" -u"$mysqluser" -p"$PASS" "$DBNAME" -se "SELECT current_ FROM $GLOBALDB;")
current_number=$(echo $current_ | grep -oh "[0-9]*")
current_letter=$(echo $current_ | grep -oh "[A-Z]*")
```

However when I try to add 1:

```
# add 1 & keep all leading zeros "000001"
next_number=$(printf %06d $(($current_number + 1)))
```

It counts to "000009" and rolls back over to "000000".

And I join as follows:

```
next_=$(echo "$current_letter$next_number")
```

And in regards to the Letter iteration I was thinking of using an Associated Array? Or brace expansion `{A..Z}`, but that is a whole different question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `bash`, numbers with leading zeros are considered as octal. To force `bash` to consider them as decimal, you can add a `10#` prefix:

```
next_number=$(printf %06d "$((10#$current_number + 1))")
```

Or with bash 3.1 or above, to avoid the forking:

```
printf -v next_number %06d "$((10#$current_number + 1))"
```

(note that it doesn't work for negative numbers as `10#-010` is seen as `10#0 - 010` in `bash`, so both `$((10#-10))` and `$((-10#-10))` expand to `-8`).

See also:

```
$ printf 'A%06d\n' {5..12}
A000005
A000006
A000007
A000008
A000009
A000010
A000011
A000012
```

Or:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {A..C}{00008..00012}
A00008
A00009
A00010
A00011
A00012
B00008
B00009
B00010
B00011
B00012
C00008
C00009
C00010
C00011
C00012
```

Or:

```
$ seq -f A%06g 5 12
A000005
A000006
A000007
A000008
A000009
A000010
A000011
A000012
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -E '$x = "A001"; say $x++ for 1 .. 1002'
```

Output:

```
A001
A002
A003
A004
A005
A006
A007
A008
A009
A010
A011
...
A996
A997
A998
A999
B000
B001
B002
```

The ++ operator handles both letters and numbers.

Comment: I know perl is included in Ubuntu, but is it a bash builtin? I have exactly 0 experience writing in perl. This clearly works.

Comment: @jmunsch: Perl is not a part of bash. It's a programming language of its own.

Comment: I did some searching. It looks as though Perl is in a lot of distros? And adding a dependency on Perl is not a problem? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @jmunsch: Perl should be there on any Linux. You can find it or install it on most *ix systems, too, as well as MS Windows.

Comment: Would this be a better perl answer? `export current_ && perl -E 'say $ENV{current_}++'` because I wasn't able to import the variable from bash to perl?

Comment: @jmunsch: I'd rather use pipes.

Answer (score 2):

For historical reasons, numerical operations in Bourne/POSIX-style shells parse integer constants with a leading `0` digit as octal rather than decimal. So `08` in an arithmetic operating is a syntax error, the successor of `07` is 8, and `010` is equivalent to `8`.

You can use normal arithmetic and then pad the numbers when printing them with the `printf` builtin.

```
next_number=$(($current_number + 1))
printf -v padded_next_number %06d "$next_number"
```

The `-v` option to `printf` is bash-specific; the POSIX way is

```
next_number=$(($current_number + 1))
padded_next_number=$(printf %06d "$next_number")
```

Here's another approach which was useful in historical systems that didn't have a `printf` command, and can still be useful for performance in the few shells that don't have `printf` as a builtin. Instead of counting from 1, count from 1000001. That way, your numbers never have to have leading zeroes. When you use the number, strip off the leading `1` digit.

```
number=1000000
while … ; do
  number=$((number+1))
  echo "${number#1}"
  …
done
```